# Compare all files of given name to another file

Tags: linux

I would like to find all files of a given name `# find / -name myfile`, compare them to another given file `/home/me/myCompareFile`, and output whether the files are identical.  Would be nice to ignore whitespace, but not necessary.  Is this possible to do from the shell?  Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do this with `grep` or `awk`

Comment: there is a utility called 
   `diff`
for just this. You can also use the exec option in find to execute diff for every file you find.

Comment: what exactly do you want to print?

Comment: @Karoly.  file1  equal, file2  not equal, file3 equal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do the following:

```
find . -name "t.c" | xargs -I % diff -q ../t.h % && echo "matches"
```

which will look for `myFile`, and for each result call `diff` to compare with `myCompareFile`, and tells you if it differs (thanks to `-q`)

for example I got `t.c` and `t.h` in current directory as an example:

```
% find . -name "t.c" | xargs -I % diff -q ./t.h % && echo "matches"
Files ./t.h and ./foo/t.c differ
Files ./t.h and ./t.c differ
% find . -name "t.c" | xargs -I % diff -q ./t.c % && echo "matches"
matches
```

even better than the `&& echo "%matches"`:

```
% find . -name "t.c" | xargs -I % diff -qs ./t.c %
Files ./t.c and ./foo/t.c differ
Files ./t.c and ./t.c are identical
```

the `-s` parameter of `diff` is :

```
   -s  --report-identical-files
          Report when two files are the same.
```

and `-q`:

```
   -q  --brief
          Output only whether files differ.
```

cf `man diff`

Comment: you're right, diff expects two files, but you're wrong saying it won't work, xargs appends the second argument.

Comment: I'm not wrong, it can pontentially append zero, one or more arguments, depending on how many files have been found.

Comment: Thanks zmo,  I almost had it, but I wasn't using the xargs, and it obviously didn't work.

Comment: ah @KarolyHorvath, right, you did not make your point in your first comment. I did wrong

Comment: [root@vps etc]# find / -name php.ini | xargs diff -q /old_vps/etc/php.ini
diff: extra operand `/etc/php.ini'
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.
[root@vps etc]#

Comment: Will this only show ones that differ, and not ones that match?

Comment: @user1032531 that why there is the `&& echo "% matches"` part, so it prints out when it matches, like in my example

Comment: `&& echo "% matches"` will never work (it's not part of the xargs command). it's very misleading to post output which shows that it works..

Comment: getting late here, and I could have sweared I have read "./t.c matches" when I tried it. But it showed "% matches".

Comment: Might want to also add -w --ignore-all-space

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in $(find / -name myfile)
do
   diff $file /home/me/myCompareFile
done
```